# How to stop automatic audio routing to plugged-in devices in Android 11?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, android-audiomanager, android-usb

I connected a Bluetooth headset to an Android 11 device and executed the following lines of code

```
audioManager?.isBluetoothScoOn = true
audioManager?.startBluetoothSco()
audioManager?.mode = AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION
audioManager?.isSpeakerphoneOn = false
```

so the audio input and output are now from the BT device.

But, if I plug in a **USB audio device or a wired headset**, the audio automatically redirects to the plugged-in device.

**I want to stop audio routing to the plugged-in device when a Bluetooth device is connected**

I tried executing this code again

```
audioManager?.isBluetoothScoOn = true
audioManager?.startBluetoothSco()
audioManager?.mode = AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION
audioManager?.isSpeakerphoneOn = false
```

to route audio back to the Bluetooth device, but the audio is not getting transferred back.

I am looking for a help in either stopping the automatic audio routing to USB device or any method to route the audio back to the Bluetooth device.